# Override existing interfaces to remove members

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

In TypeScript, given an existing type in scope  is there a way to redeclare that type in order to remove some members?

Specifically I want to remove functions like `toExponential()` from `Number` and have intellisense reflect that change on all numbers thereafter

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove `toExponential()` from the `Number` interface?

Comment: Yeah but I think they're synonymous in TS? But if not then yeah that's what I mean. Types for which I don't control their initial declaration and/or are built in

Comment: I don't think you can merge/override it to remove it, but you can replace `lib.es5.d.ts` with your own version excluding it.

Comment: And above, I don't know what "`isExponential()` is.  Do you mean `toExponential()`?

Comment: @jcalz I do, sorry. Writing on mobile client off top of my head whilst walking!

Comment: @jcalz replacing the d.ts was what I thought it might take.. but I'm not sure that'll work if the user already has the original in their project

Comment: Make a copy of lib.es5.d.ts (in older versions lib.d.ts) remove toExponential, then include this copy as reference to your project and complie with `--noLib` or `noLib: true` in tsconfig.json

Comment: So, you mean include that hacked file with the typings for my npm module package? ps. post it as an answer so you can get credit if it seems like the best approach!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just inserted this at the top of my existing `d.ts` file I was writing for the project:

```
// Prevent Intellisense suggesting default ES interfaces
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
```

This lives inside a `typings/` folder from the root (though not sure that folder structure convention is necessary in newer TS setups).

This prevents VSCode suggesting ES style interfaces for completion. I can then copy over the ES interfaces from the default lib into this file as I need them (at present I need none!).

Thanks to the commenters above for helping me arrive at this solution. It's working well so far!